# Passing argument in a Subset using function in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I want to make a function that will accept a argument and use it into subset and then plot a graph with multiple line. I wrote following code

```
plot.new( )
rest_o_noise <- function(noise_level, color) {
    rest_o_noise_level = subset(yelp_flat, attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2!= "NA", eval(parse(text=noise_level)))
    rest_o_noise_level <- rest_o_noise_level %>% 
    group_by(attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2) %>% 
    summarise(n=mean(stars))
    lines(rest_o_noise_level, stars, col=color)
}



rest_o_noise("attributes.NoiseLevel=='loud'", "green")
rest_o_noise("attributes.NoiseLevel=='low'", "green")
```

I am getting a error:

Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2 is unknown

Just to be clear attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2 is present in csv.

final output should look like:

[image]

Is this correct way to plot? 
Please help!!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Also check the column names if it is the same as you mentioned in the function

Comment: I think you should get an error saying there is an unused argument. `rest_o_noise` set to take only one argument, then you use two...

Comment: @Headpoint sorry I made edit. Previously I made mistake.

Comment: @akrun I have included final output. Please let me know how to plot graph like this.

Comment: It is difficult to give an answer not knowing the how your data look like - for all we know you are making a mistake... are you trying to get a subset of rows using `attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2!= "NA"` and also `noise_level`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a subset of rows from `iris` data using a conditional in a string

```
Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
noise_level <- "Species == \"setosa\""

subset(iris, Sepal.Length == 5.1 & 
       eval(parse(text=noise_level)))

#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
# 20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
# 22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
# 24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
# 40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
# 47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
```

In your case, it would be something like what is below which conditions on the 
columns `attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2` and  `attributes.NoiseLevel` to select subset of rows.

```
plot.new( )
rest_o_noise <- function(noise_level, color) {
  rest_o_noise_level = subset(yelp_flat, 
   (attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2!= "NA") &
                              eval(parse(text=noise_level)))
  rest_o_noise_level <- rest_o_noise_level %>% 
    group_by(attributes.RestaurantsPriceRange2) %>% 
    summarise(n=mean(stars))
  lines(rest_o_noise_level, stars, col=color)
}

rest_o_noise("attributes.NoiseLevel==\"loud\"", "green")
```

---

You can, of course,  select a single column, as below. However, why you would use the "==" for that is not clear, hence I assumed you are trying to select a subset of rows.

```
noise_level <- "Petal.Width"
subset(iris, Sepal.Length == 5.1,   
         eval(parse(text=noise_level)))

#      Petal.Width
# 1          0.2
# 18         0.3
# 20         0.3
# 22         0.4
# 24         0.5
# 40         0.2
# 45         0.4
# 47         0.2
# 99         1.1
```